# VS 2017 Add > Docker Support breaks build - "CleanWorkspace" task failed unexpectedly (console app)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

First off I'm using .NET 4.6.1.  Does Docker with VS 2017 not work with anything but .NET Core?

I used the new feature `Add > Docker Support` from the context menu, and it created a bunch of files.  Here's my Dockerfile (haven't touched it since it was auto-created):

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\app\nameofmyapp.exe"]
```

When I build, I get the following error:

> The "CleanWorkspace" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: The Compose file
>   '...\docker-compose.yml'
>   is invalid because: services.pas.parsemicroservice.build.context
>   contains null, which is an invalid type, it should be a string.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  pas.parsemicroservice:
    image: pas.parsemicroservice
    build:
      context: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

If I add a `.` to context (as the error implies the `null` there is the problem), I get a different error:

> There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph
>   involving target "DockerCleanServiceReferences".

Is this all a result of using the wrong .NET framework, or are my files set up wrong?  (I am a Docker n00b to be sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Regarding your circular dependency issue, make sure your SLN and CSPROJ files are not in the same folder. Meaning that when you first create a solution, make sure to check the box that says "create directory for solution".

Docker support for non .Net Core applications is definitely supported in VS 2017 as shown at the 9:15 mark of this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/T111

Your `context` should point to the directory where your `Dockerfile` exists.  This path should be relative to where your docker-compose.yml file is located.

Compose file version 2 Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#context

Comment: They are both in the same folder, so the correct entry for that would be `.`, correct? When I use that for context I get the error about
"There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "DockerCleanServiceReferences"."  That's good news to hear that non-Core applications are supported!

Comment: Confirmed--if the SLN and CSPROJ files are in different folders, error goes away.  Thanks!!