# Unable to create migration using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am using Rider to develop a C# Console Application.
I have current version of dotnet - 3.1.101. plus

```
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
3.1.1
```

When I try to run the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration
```

I get this error:

```
 error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "GetEFProjectMetadata". [/home/venelin/GameServer/WorldServer/WorldServer.csproj]
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

I haven't created any Migrations folder or anything. I have just installed EFCore, however I can not run the command to create new migration.

How can i fix it?

P.S.
This is the list of the packages I have installed:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" version="1.0.19269.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI" version="1.0.19235.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="3.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.11" targetFramework="net461" /
```

>

Comment: Try to specify project name: add-migration -Name NewMigration -Project "WorldServer"

Comment: When I run `dotnet ef migrations add-migration -Name NewMigration -Project "WorldServer"` there is no difference. I get the same error about `There is a circular dependency`

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin can the problem be because I haven't created Migrations or Data folder? I haven't created any specific DBContext as well. Is this a problem ?

Comment: Check each data model you have. There could be a circular reference. This happens when a parent class is inheriting from a child class. Alternatively, you should try add-migration -Name [Name] -Project "[ProjectName]" in PackageManagerConsole within VS

Comment: I have created brand new empty console solution and there I am having the same error. What can be causing this issue ?

Comment: @VenelinVasilev go through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337080/9936356

Comment: Please, also consider this issue on GH: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14399

Comment: I think you should check for circular dependency between projects in your solution.